# Stripe Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have a stripe webhook that call a Firebase function. In this function I need to verify that this request comes from Stripe servers. Here is the code :

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_****");
const endpointSecret = 'whsec_****';
const app = require('express')();

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    verify: function (req, res, buf) {
        var url = req.originalUrl;
        if (url.startsWith('/webhook')) {
            req.rawBody = buf.toString()
        }
    }
}));

app.post('/webhook/example', (req, res) => {
    let sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    try {
        console.log(req.bodyRaw)
        let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, endpointSecret);
        console.log(event);
        res.status(200).end()

        // Do something with event
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).end()
    }
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

As mentioned in [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures), I have to use raw body to perform this security check.

I have tried with my current code and with :

```js
app.use(require('body-parser').raw({type: '*/*'}));
```

But I always get this error :

```
Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Cloud Functions automatically [parses body content of known types](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests).  If you're getting JSON, then it's already parsed and available to you in `req.body`.  You shouldn't need to add other body parsing middleware.

If you need to process the raw data, you should use `req.rawBody`, but I don't think you'll need to do that here.

Comment: I just had to use `req.rawBody` in `constructEvent()`.

Stupid mistake, thank you.

Comment: Facing the same issue in Java, any suggestions, please

Comment: To get `req.rawBody` defined, I had to do `app.use(express.json({verify: (req,res,buf) => { req.rawBody = buf }}));` instead of only `app.use(express.json());`. Alternatively I think I could have just accessed `req.body` before `app.use(express.json())`, but this way I can access the raw body anywhere.

Comment: sorry, req.rawBody was good. I mistakenly set down arrow. now my vote is locked I can't switch to up arrow.

Comment: @pref That's odd.  You should be able to change your vote at any time.

Comment: when I click on Up arrow it says:
"You last voted on this answer Dec 20 ... Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" 
!! 
It seems there is a time window after initial vote to update it and it can't change after unless the original text is updated.

Comment: @sammy I had to do this also for my app to work

Comment: `req.rawBody` worked for me

Answer (score 60):

2 things to note:

1. Make sure you're using the correct webhook secret. It's unique per webhook url!

[image]

2. if you're using stripe CLI, change the stripe secret to cli

[image]

---

If using Firebase cloud functions:

pass `req.rawBody` instead of `req.body` to `constructEvent`

```js
const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.rawBody,
        sig,
        STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
      );
```

---

If using `Next.js` Vercel function:

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"]!;

  const body = await buffer(req);
  const event = stripeObj.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, key);

  console.log("webhook verified");
  switch (event.type) {
    case "checkout.session.completed":

    default:
      console.error(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
  }

  return res.status(200).json({});
}

const buffer = (req: NextApiRequest) => {
  return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks: Buffer[] = [];

    req.on("data", (chunk: Buffer) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    req.on("end", () => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });

    req.on("error", reject);
  });
};
```

check for other servers: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/tree/master/examples/webhook-signing

Comment: Yes you are right... I was using the webhook id... Very confusing

Comment: Your answer helped! I was using the incorrect webhook secret!

Comment: Where I can find this secret key?

Comment: Yes, the body passed in should be of str, instead of the converted json body.

Comment: OMG! Stripe has a webhook builder tool and it provides the secret, but after I added the route, the secret was different. Thanks a million for this tip

Comment: your answer helped! I was using webhook secret for local url.

Comment: This did not work for me. If you are using TypeScript it's fine but if you are using javascript it's not a useful solution. Currently stuck trying to access the raw body but because the req that comes into the Next.js route is an instance of incomingMessage it can't be buffer'd and it also is resistant to the chunking process your solution describes. ready to scream and throw my computer out of the room. typescript is not worth rewriting my entire codebase because this ONE SITUATION needs it.

Answer (score 40):

Here is what is working for me:

**add this line:**

```
app.use('/api/subs/stripe-webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: "*/*"}))
```

(The first argument specifies which route we should use the raw body parser on. See the [app.use()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) reference doc.)

**just before this line:**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

(it doesn't affect all your operation, just this: '/api/subs/stripe-webhook')

> Note: If you are using Express 4.16+ you can replace bodyParser by express:

```
app.use('/api/subs/stripe-webhook', express.raw({type: "*/*"}));
app.use(express.json());
```

**Then:**

```
const endpointSecret = 'whsec_........'

const stripeWebhook = async (req, res) => {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

    let eventSecure = {}
    try {
        eventSecure = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, endpointSecret);
        //console.log('eventSecure :', eventSecure);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('err.message :', err.message);
        res.status(400).send(`Webhook Secure Error: ${err.message}`)
        return
    }
    res.status(200).send({ received: true });
}
```

Comment: This is great! I didn't know you could specify an exact path in `app.use()`. Much more elegant than the other answers that use `verify` to check for a special situation (and convert the raw body themselves rather than rely on Express.js's built-in feature for handling raw stuff).

Comment: Excellent, excellent answer. Being able to override the standard functionality by path is a game changer. The official documentation should include this caveat because it's a very common pattern in express development.

Answer (score 24):

Here is code which is working for me:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  verify: function (req, res, buf) {
    var url = req.originalUrl;
    if (url.startsWith('/stripe')) {
       req.rawBody = buf.toString();
    }
  }
}));
```

And then pass the req.rawBody for verification

```js
stripe.checkWebHook(req.rawBody, signature);
```

Reference: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341

Answer (score 17):

2021 - Solution

I faced that error, and after a lot research I could not figure out the problem easily, but finally I could do it based in my architecture below:

```
//App.js

this.server.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/webhook')) {
    next();
  } else {
    express.json()(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

```
//routes.js

routes.post(
  '/webhook-payment-intent-update',
  bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }),

  //your stripe logic (Im using a controller, but wherever)
  (req, res) => {
    stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(...)
  }
)
```

**Two big warnings to pay attention:**

- Make sure to send the `req.headers['stripe-signature']`
- Make sure that your `endpointSecret` is right, if not it will still saying the same error

**Tips:**

- Test it locally by installing the Stripe CLI: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test
- Verify your key on stripe dashboard or you can also make sure if you have the right key by verifying you stripe log as below:

[image: webhook secret key example]

I hope it helps you. :)

Comment: Making sure that the secret for the local test webhooks is correct was a great tip that solved my issue!

Comment: Cool! @Manuel :).

Comment: I keep getting this error : **Unable to extract timestamp and signatures from header**

Comment: What is actually **stripe-signature**?. should I pass exactly stripe-signature or something else would come in that place?

Comment: Thanks. Previously I used different webhook secret key

Comment: Same mistake. Use a previous webhook secret key.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you have to select the right webhook secret.
I spent a lot of time testing, I was using the webhook id, instead of webhook secret.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Use JSON parser for all non-webhook routes
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      const url = req.originalUrl;
      if (url.startsWith('/api/stripe/webhook')) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      }
    }
  })
);
```

The above code will look fine for the above answers. But even I was made one mistake. After put the same thing I got the same error.

Finally, I've figured it out if you're configured body-parser below the `rawBody` code then it'll work.

Like this

```js
// Use JSON parser for all non-webhook routes
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      const url = req.originalUrl;
      if (url.startsWith('/api/stripe/webhook')) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      }
    }
  })
);
```

```js
// Setup express response and body parser configurations
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Hopefully, it'll help someone.

Comment: After spending whole day trying several solutions this one finally worked for me as of today - 6th July 2021. There is small change though , body-parser is deprecated, `express.json({...})` and `express.raw({...})` can be directly used.

Comment: That's correct We can use it directly instead of body-parser. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is late but will help others

[Github answer](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing)

```js
    const payload = req.body
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']
    const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
    const secret = 'webhook_secret';
    const header = stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString({
            payload: payloadString,
            secret,
    });
    
     let event;
     try {
          event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payloadString, header, secret);
    
     } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
            return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
     }

       switch (event.type) {
           case 'checkout.session.completed': {
       ......
    enter code here
```

Comment: You have to be very careful with this code because the real signature is not actually verified

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to add a stripe webhook into your NextJS API Route, here's how to do so ([ref](https://github.com/dijonmusters/build-a-saas-with-next-js-supabase-and-stripe/blob/master/21-subscribe-to-stripe-webhooks-using-next-js-api-routes/pages/api/stripe-hooks.js)):

```js
import { buffer } from "micro";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export const config = { api: { bodyParser: false } };

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
  const signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
  const signingSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET || '';
  const reqBuffer = await buffer(req);

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(reqBuffer, signature, signingSecret);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook error: ${error?.message}`);
  }

  console.log({ event });

  res.send({ received: true });
};

export default handler;
```

This is using `buffer` from the `micro` library, in combination with the modifying the default [API request](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/request-helpers) to use `request's` rawbody. In some frameworks (like NextJs), `rawBody` doesn't come OOTB, hence the workaround of retrieving the `rawbody` by `reqBuffer`, which is needed in the `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent` event.

Answer (score 3):

I spent countless hours checking the following:

1. Correct webhook endpoint secret.
   Note: It starts with `whsec_.....`

You can find it here by clicking on 'Reveal' under Signing secret of your webhook.
[image]

2. Make sure your framework doesn't manipulate the raw body.

You can find code examples for your framework [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-official-libraries).
In my case, I was using Express. I made sure that I'm correctly parsing the raw body in the `/webhook` controller.

```
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {}
```

**But, it didn't work!!**.

I was getting the same error again and again.

This was due to the fact that I used `app.use(express.json())` previously in the `server.js` file. This converted any raw body to json way before `express.raw({type: 'application/json'})` was called in the controller.

Here's the fix:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === "/api/payment/webhook") {
        next(); // Do nothing with the body because I need it in a raw state.
    } else {
        express.json()(req, res, next); // ONLY do express.json() if the received request is NOT a WebHook from Stripe.
    }
});
```

**Still, it didn't work for me!!**

The reason was, I used `https://api.myCompany.com/api/payment/webhook/` in the webhook url on Stipe dashboard while disabling `express.json` on `req.originalUrl === "/api/payment/webhook"`. Note that leading slash in webhook url.

In short, you need to make sure, you've entered the correct webhook endpoint in Stripe dashboard.

This is very basic, but it gets ignored. I updated the webhook endpoint as `https://api.myCompany.com/api/payment/webhook` and it was resolved.

A leading slash can do a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to obtain data from one webhook but not from a second one: the problem was that the secret key I used was the same as the one used for the first webhook, but I found out that every webhook has a different key, that's way I got that same message.

Answer (score 1):

AWS API Gateway + Lambda (Express.js CRUD) I'm using this for Stripe webhook endpoint and it works for me:

```
app.use(require('body-parser').text({ type: "*/*" }));
```

Comment: Legend, this is the only solution worked for me. Tyvm.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when sending a test webhook from the Stripe dashboard after I had renamed a firebase cloud function. All my other functions were working fine. Solved by re-setting in the terminal
**firebase functions:config:set stripe.webhook_signature="Your webhook signing secret"**
(if you're using that) and redeploying the functions **firebase deploy --only functions**

On a second occasion I solved the problem by rolling the stripe signature in the stripe dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this script

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      req.rawBody = buf;
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: How is this better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/54956700/6541288 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53899407/6541288 ?

Answer (score 0):

My fave was combining two of above great answers.

Then you can use req.rawbody when you construct the event.

Replace "webhook" with whatever route you wish you have a raw body for.

```
app.use(
  "/webhook",
  express.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      req.rawBody = buf.toString();
    },
  })
);

BEFORE

app.use(express.json());
```

Works well if you are using routes and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

To use raw body in express with a specific endpoint in a seperated middleware, my solution is just enabling router to use express.raw for the webhook endpoint.
-node.js v12
-express.js v4.17.1

```
export const handleBodyRequestParsing = (router: Router): void => {
  router.use('/your_webhook_endpoint', express.raw({ type: '*/*' }))
  router.use(express.json({ limit: '100mb' }))
  router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the **Quick Tip** which may save your hours !**

If you are adding express payment to your exciting express app sometimes you may already pass your request as `json` in the beginning of application by using express middleware `app.use(json());` or any other middleware (Bodyparser for example).

If you are doing that then change that to omit your webhook url

Exmaple:
Assume your payment webhook url is `/paments/webhhok`

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.includes("/payments/webhook")) {
    next();
  } else {
    express.json()(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Stripe in Express, if you have the following line in your code;
app.use(express.json());
it is going to prevent you from providing the raw body to the Stripe even when you explicitly set "bodyParser.raw", which will throw an error. This was the reason my code failed. Finally sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above and no one worked, and figured out that the only solution was not to use express at all for this endpoint. you just have to create another http function

```
export const webhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']
    const endpointSecret = 'web_secret'

    const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      req.rawBody,
      sig,
      endpointSecret
    )
    console.log(event.data.object)

    res.status(200).send(event.data.object)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('ocorreu um erro', err)

    res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
this.app.use(
  express.json({
    verify: function (req, res, buf) {
      //@ts-ignore
      var url = req.originalUrl;
      if (url.includes("/webhook")) {
        //@ts-ignore
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      }
    },
  })
);
this.app.use(express.json());
```

Then implement this https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-official-libraries

Answer (score 0):

I saw a better solution by just not reinventing the wheel and the reason why is a properly called **rawBody** where you can see the dev doc in the code that is "Whether to register the raw request body on the request. Use req.rawBody." so by just setting this to true like:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    ....
    rawBody: true,
    ...
  });
```

so that later in any controller you will see the **rawBody** property included in the request. So in the code you can pass this to the stripe api like:

```
const rawBody = req.rawBody; // you will have access to the raw body to send thie to stripe
this.stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        rawBody,
        ...here the signature...,
        ...here the secret...,
      );
```

I hope this save hours or days for some devs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're [forwarding to localhost](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#local-listener) using the stripe CLI make sure you use whatever signing secret is provided by the CLI output.
[image: cli signing secret]

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying my MERN stack web application which included the stripe webhooks.I was using express.js and I was parsing all my requests with this line of code

```
app.use(express.json());
```

and then In my webhook API I was using the following code to createEvent

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
```

**Hence it produces the error for me.So what I did to remove Error is **

1. Comment the line

   app.use(express.json());

Even if the API call is above this line , then it still parses the request body and hence cause issues in verification by the stripe.So remove this line if your using in order to parse your requests.

2.Add this code in your index.js/main file

```
// Middleware to handle different types of requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Check if the request is for the '/webhook' endpoint
    if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
        // Continue to the next middleware or route handler
        next();
    } else {
        // If not a '/webhook' request, use the express.json() middleware
        express.json()(req, res, next);
    }

});
```

3.This was my code for the Web hooks API in Express.js

```
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), 
async (request, response) => {
const payload = request.body;
const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
const header = stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString({
payload: payloadString,
secret: endpointSecret,
});




console.log("in it");
   const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  
   ');

   let event;

   try {

    const checkoutDate = new Date();



    const rawBody = request.body;
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payloadString, header, 
    endpointSecret);
```

Hope so it can save time for some folks.