# Stripe Webhook Endpoint Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm seeing the following error on my WebHook handler:

`Webhook Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing`

Following this example, I updated my code from `req.body` to `req.rawBody`.

[Stripe Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899365/stripe-error-no-signatures-found-matching-the-expected-signature-for-payload)

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/webhook', raw({ type: 'application/json' }), async (req, res) => {
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    let event;

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            req.rawBody,
            sig,
            stripeWebhookSigningKey
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
        ...
    } else if (event.type === 'account.updated') {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: How did you end up fixing it ?

Comment: It turns out my stripeWebhookSigningKey was incorrect (was using dev instead of staging)