# Why is the event not processed on my server side (Stripe-CLI)?

Tags: javascript, express

I have read the [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#handle-the-checkoutsessioncompleted-event) regarding processing of payments and so on, but it doesn't work for me.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
const endpointSecret = 'whsec_*';

router.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const payload = request.body;
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
    console.log(event)
  } catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
    const session = event.data.object;

    // Fulfill the purchase...
    fulfillOrder(session);
  }

  response.status(200);
});
```

function that I am calling, just in  case

```
const fulfillOrder = (session) => {
  // TODO: fill me in
  console.log("Fulfilling order", session);
}
```

But when I try to trigger an event, I don't see no messages in the Terminal of the server. This makes me unsecure if it is working or no, so I can't do any further actions.
Here is a screenshot from the dashboard, just to prove that it is all running up as needed, in my opinion.
[image]
[image: Stripe-CLI]

Comment: To me it looks like your code is failing in the try...catch block, and issues a 400 response, which we can see in your logs.  So I guess stripe.webhooks.constructEvent is generating an error.  Can you log it and find out what it is?

Comment: please telp me what should i write in the terminal to make it run?

Comment: @James send the command pls

Comment: in your `catch(err)` block you could try `console.log(err.message)`

Comment: oh, cool, i see. No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Comment: Now you have the error, you can search it, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899365/stripe-error-no-signatures-found-matching-the-expected-signature-for-payload