# Stripe webhook ERROR: signature verification failed: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

This is a stripe webhook i have been trying to configure. My main problem is the fact thay the payload is empty when testing the cloud function. No matter what i do i always get the signature verification failed error. I added log statements to check the incoming data, and when i test it with the stripe cli the 'payload' logs correctly, when i test with Insomnia or curl the payload logs. However, when i try to do the same thing with the Google Cloud Platform hosted flask app, it gives me the error, as well as logging the payload as just an empty string. The sig_header, and endpoint_secret log correctly, and the endpoint secret matches what is in my stripe dashboard. The flask app is a GCP hosted cloud function.

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def stripe_webhook():
    event = None
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)

     logging.info(f"Raw request payload: {payload}")

     sig_header = request.headers.get('Stripe-Signature')
     logging.info(f"Stripe-Signature header: {sig_header}")

     content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
     logging.info(f"Request Content-Type: {content_type}")

     logging.info(f'endpoint secret: {endpoint_secret}')

     if endpoint_secret:
         try:
             event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
                 payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
             )
         except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
             logging.error(f"Webhook signature verification failed: {e}")
             return jsonify(success=False)
    event = None


       
    if event and event['type'] == 'customer.subscription.deleted':
        subscription = event['data']['object']
        customer_id = subscription['customer']
        handle_subscription_deleted(customer_id)

        return jsonify(success=True)

    return jsonify(success=False)
```

Comment: Include the output from the logging.

Comment: @JohnHanley there is no output. That's the problem. The payload logs an empty string.

Comment: Show the `curl` command you are using to test the function. Also, double-check the indentation of the code that you posted. You set event to None and then check it.

Comment: Cloud Functions automatically parses body content of known types. If you're getting JSON, then it's already parsed and available to you in req.body. You shouldn't need to add other body parsing middleware. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899365/) by Doug Stevenson  for more information.

Comment: @HemanthKumar I've done request.data, request.get_data(), request.get_data(text=True), request.stream.read(), all with the same result of an empty string.